# Information on Kontakt file format

Tags: software, sampling, kontakt

I'm trying to find information regarding the Kontakt file format, that goes into specific enough detail about the structure of a Kontakt sampler library file that one would be able to write a computer script to manipulate and edit the data it contains in raw binary format, and rewrite it back.

Does anyone know where I could find formatting information like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've tried with Kontakt files:
Comparing two files with a minor parameter change on a Hex editor.
The format is proprietary and maybe obfuscated.
You can always contact Native Instruments for more details.

http://www.native-instruments.com/fr/support/contact-support/tech-support/

btw if you have any answer from them I would love to hear from you on this post or on mp.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand that the format may be proprietary, but deliberately obfuscating it to me would seem pathological - you'd think it would be in their interests to make it a de-facto standard and that would be assisted by having the format details open.

I think someone out there has already written a format converter that goes from Akai to Kontakt (I'm actually interested in the reverse) so it can't be a complete mystery.

Comment: You can also ask them how they got the format specifications.
But as will see both programs aren't open-source.
So it might be some chance the devs had to pay NI a lincence for the file format

http://www.extranslator.com/
http://www.chickensys.com/products2/translator/

Hope to have a feedback on this ;)